# How do I implement the zoom-in-zoom-out SMOOTHLY in Android? Relevant to SurfaceView with RTMP streaming

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, zooming, onmeasure

I am implementing a feature that can zoom in or zoom out when playing RTMP streaming with SurfaceView object. I have done some research and I decided to calculate the size and the position first and use the onMeasure() method to re-build the view.

Now I have a problem that the object doesn't really follow the position I set during zooming. The effect I would like to implement is like this **[video](http://youtu.be/iRKer1AUfd0)** (which shows the behaviour of the iOS version of my app), and I recorded **[another video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1DYqMuf-9M)** to show what I have done so far. The object would shift more frequently if I use the same position as the iOS version app. It is not smooth at all and might cause a poor user experience.

My observation to the behaviour is that the object of SurfaceView would re-size its width and height with fixed position x and y as the zoom function triggered. Then, the object would shift backward which might result from following the layout of its parent. I printed log messages out and found that the position x and y would have been changed when onMeasure() was triggered. Although I have set the position in the function, it would still be changed when the process went to onLayout(). Since onLayout() is called as soon as the onMeasure() finished, so I don't see any possible timing to set the position to avoid the shifting.

The following is what I have done:
Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelaytiveView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <com.player.adapter.RtmpLiveSurfaceview
            android:id="@+id/goLiveView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code:

```
public class RtmpLiveSurfaceview extends SurfaceView 
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_PIXEL_WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int DEFAULT_PIXEL_HEIGHT = 720;
    private float INIT_WIDTH;
    private float INIT_HEIGHT;
    private float WIDTH = 0;
    private float HEIGHT = 0;
    private float SCALER = (float) 1.0;
    private float TAG_POINT_X = 0;
    private float TAG_POINT_Y = 0;

    private float INIT_DIST = 0;
    SurfaceHolder mholder;

    static final int ZOOM = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
    }
    @Override
    protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        setX(TAG_POINT_X);
        setY(TAG_POINT_Y);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
        int width = getDefaultSize(DEFAULT_PIXEL_WIDTH, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(DEFAULT_PIXEL_HEIGHT, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (DEFAULT_PIXEL_WIDTH > 0 && DEFAULT_PIXEL_HEIGHT > 0)
        {
            if ( DEFAULT_PIXEL_WIDTH * height  > width * DEFAULT_PIXEL_HEIGHT )
            {
                height = width * DEFAULT_PIXEL_HEIGHT / DEFAULT_PIXEL_WIDTH;
            } 
            else if ( DEFAULT_PIXEL_WIDTH * height  < width * DEFAULT_PIXEL_HEIGHT )
            {
                width = height * DEFAULT_PIXEL_WIDTH / DEFAULT_PIXEL_HEIGHT;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        INIT_WIDTH = width;
        INIT_HEIGHT = height;
        if(WIDTH == 0)
        {
            WIDTH = INIT_WIDTH;
            HEIGHT = INIT_HEIGHT;
        }
        int wmode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int hmode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int)WIDTH, wmode);
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int)HEIGHT, hmode);
        setX(TAG_POINT_X);
        setY(TAG_POINT_Y);
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    }
    public void init() 
    {
        mholder = getHolder();
        mholder.setSizeFromLayout();
        mholder.addCallback(new Callback() 
        {
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
            {
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent MEvent) 
    {
        switch (MEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            {
                if(MEvent.getPointerCount() >= 2)
                {
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    INIT_DIST = spacing(MEvent);
                    break;
                }
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                if (mode == ZOOM) 
                {
                    if(MEvent.getPointerCount() >= 2)
                    {
                        float newDist = spacing(MEvent);
                        float tmp_scaler = (float) (((newDist - INIT_DIST) * 0.1 + INIT_DIST) / INIT_DIST);
                        if((tmp_scaler * WIDTH) > (2.0 * INIT_WIDTH))
                            tmp_scaler = (float) (((newDist - INIT_DIST) * 0.01 + INIT_DIST) / INIT_DIST);
                        WIDTH = getWidth();
                        HEIGHT = getHeight();
                        if (((tmp_scaler * WIDTH) >= (1.0 * INIT_WIDTH)) && ((tmp_scaler * WIDTH) <= (4.0 * INIT_WIDTH)))
                        {
                            SCALER = tmp_scaler;
                            TAG_POINT_X = getX();
                            if((TAG_POINT_X + WIDTH * SCALER) < INIT_WIDTH)
                                TAG_POINT_X = INIT_WIDTH - WIDTH * SCALER;
                            else if(TAG_POINT_X > 0)
                                TAG_POINT_X = 0;
                            TAG_POINT_Y = getY();
                            if((TAG_POINT_Y + HEIGHT * SCALER) < INIT_HEIGHT)
                                TAG_POINT_Y = INIT_HEIGHT - HEIGHT * SCALER;
                            else if(TAG_POINT_Y > 0)
                                TAG_POINT_Y = 0;
                            WIDTH = WIDTH * SCALER;
                            HEIGHT = HEIGHT * SCALER;
                            requestLayout();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? If it is not possible to implement zoom-in-zoom-out function with SurfaceView, is there any suggested solution? Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @ShengChingLin It would be nice if you could share what you ended up doing?

Answer (score 1):

Moving and resizing the SurfaceView is probably not the right answer. The Surface part of the SurfaceView is a separate layer whose size and position is managed by the Window Manager, not the app's View hierarchy, so animating a SurfaceView's attributes tends to look janky.

One possible approach would be to switch from SurfaceView to TextureView. You can get rid of the layout code and just use the TextureView's transformation matrix. See for example the difference in the way the video aspect ratio is handled in the Grafika movie playback classes -- [PlayMoveSurfaceActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java).clickPlayStop() uses an AspectFrameLayout, while the TextureView-based [PlayMovieActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java).clickPlayStop() leaves the View alone and just tweaks the matrix.

Another approach is to keep the SurfaceView, but send the camera preview to a SurfaceTexture and render the output to an OpenGL ES texture.  See [TextureFromCameraActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureFromCameraActivity.java) for an example. Note how the zoom feature is implemented by updating the texture coordinates.  This is much more flexible, but you'd need to incorporate the GLES setup code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am still working on it and I will report it later in this week. Hope it will work!